# android ndk build issue (..ld.exe: ./jni: No such file: Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, build, java-native-interface

I try to build my project. but, it gives error:

```
C:\svn\my-ndk-project>c:\development\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd
SharedLibrary  : libsprat-jni.so
c:/development/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/wi
ndows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./jni: No such file: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libsprat-jni.so] Error 1
```

I use win7 64 bit. I give all permission to android-ndk path to Users. I also check `libstlport_static.a` 's permission. but I couldnot to solve problem. what should I do ?

Comment: which library you want to build...???

Comment: Prebuilt       : libstlport_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/

Comment: this is the name after building give me the name of library..

Comment: I found the problem. I added a line to Android.mk. it was, LOCAL_LDLIBS =./jni -lstlport. and make couldnt read that. now,I remove it and I give permission 777 to all ndk sources, and it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when running on Windows.

I solved it by giving the .so files a full control permission

Answer (score -1):

1. find ./obj/local/armeabi/libstlport_static.a and delete it
2. run ndk-build again and it will not be built successfully,ignore the error
3. find the new libstlport_static.a at the path of ./obj/local/armeabi/, execute chmod 777 libstlport_static.a
4. rebuild your library, it will success.